# Excel VBA call the values to the formula

Tags: vba, excel

i having a problem here and is it possible to call rowCount in the formula of RC ( row & column ) ?

```
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Sheets("VBAResult").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    rowCount = Selection.Count
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(ABC!R[rowCount]C[-3] <> """",ABC!R[rowCount]C[-3],"""")"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible:

```
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ABC!R[" & rowCount & "]C[-3] <>"""",ABC!R[" & rowCount & "]C[-3],"""")"
```

Btw, consider about avoiding using select [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)